# Override Vuetify 2.0 sass variable $heading-font-family

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

In Vuetify 2.0.0-beta.0 I try to override the default variable $heading-font-family. This isn't working. However I can override e.g. $body-font-family, $font-size-root or $btn-border-radius.

I've followed the documentation from https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/theme

My main.scss looks like this:

```
// main.scss

@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

// The variables I want to modify
$font-size-root: 16px;
$body-font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
$heading-font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$btn-border-radius: 8px;
```

My .vue file has a template with this HTML:

```html
// in my vue Template

...
<div class="hello">
  <h1 class="display-1">{{ msg }}</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <v-btn color="pink" dark>Click me</v-btn>
</div>
...
```

When I inspect the H1 in the console, I expect it to have a font family of 'Open Sans', sans-serif. Instead I see "Roboto", sans-serif. This was the default value of $body-font-family before it was overridden in my custom main.scss

As I said, the other overrides from my main.scss are working fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It probably has to do with setting the $headings as an 'object' in Vuetify _variables.scss. In my opinion the best solution would be to use the fix that Bootstrap uses. See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22891#issuecomment-316463806 This would make the heading font a lot easier to customize.

Comment: the same happens to me

Answer (score 10):

I've tried all the solutions presented here but nothing worked.

What did work was following this https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables

*create a directory `scss` in `src`* (not /src/styles/scss/ or any other variant). And there place your new variables value.

```
// /src/scss/variables.scss

$body-font-family: 'Less';
$heading-font-family: $body-font-family;

// Required for modifying core defaults
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
```

Comment: SASS variable changes can take a bit longer to compile. Keep an eye on the development server, or restart it to be sure the changes take effect.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @Claudiu

Answer (score 3):

Problem is caused by `!important` on `font-family` for vuetify typography helper classes.
My solution was to achieve same level of css specificity in my `variables.scss` file, and because it is loaded after vuetify typography helper classes it will override them.

My `variables.scss` file:

```
//all variable changes need to happen before @import
$body-font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
//specificity needs to be taken into consideration for some components
//because !important has been assigned to their css
//https://dev.to/emmabostian/css-specificity-1kca
html,
body,
.v-application {
  font-family: $body-font-family;
}
//added all typography helper classes because of css specificity override
//https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/typography#typography 
.v-application {
    .display-4,
    .display-3,
    .display-2,
    .display-1,
    .headline,
    .title,
    .subtitle-1,
    .subtitle-2,
    .body-1,
    .body-2,
    .caption,
    .overline
    {
        font-family: $body-font-family;
    }
}
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss';
```

If this doesn't work for you, inspect the element which defaults to Roboto font, click on the `font-family` attribute and see which css classes cause that, then add those classes to css selectors in `variables.scss` file (eg. `.v-application .title`)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with $body-font-family; what I was trying was:

```
$body-font-family : 'ArbitrayFont' !important;
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
```

However, after a lot of struggle, I found that after changing the default vuetify sass variable I should assign the variable to the desired elements like this:

```
 $body-font-family : 'ArbitrayFont' !important;
 html,
body,
.v-application,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: $body-font-family;
}

@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
```

Comment: According to [the Caveats sections](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#caveats), this is the example of what **NOT** to do. These styles "will be added to every component and will cause duplicate CSS in your app".

Answer (score 1):

Hello after a while I harmonize all my fonts with the following.

```
// src/sass/main.scss
$my-font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif !default;


@import "~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass";
$body-font-family: $my-font-family;

@import "~vuetify/src/styles/settings/variables";
$body-font-family: $my-font-family;

//Rewrite all the headings
$headings: map-merge($headings, (
        'h1': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'h1'),
                        (
                                'font-family': $body-font-family
                        )
        ),
        'h2': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'h2'),
                        (
                                'font-family': $body-font-family
                        )
        ),
        'h3': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'h3'),
                        (
                                'font-family': $body-font-family
                        )
        ),
        'h4': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'h4'),
                        (
                                'font-family': $body-font-family
                        )
        ),
        'h5': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'h5'),
                        ( 'font-family': $body-font-family )
        ),
        'h6': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'h6'),
                        ( 'font-family': $body-font-family )
        ),
        'subtitle-1': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'subtitle-1'),
                        ( 'font-family': $body-font-family)
        ),
        'subtitle-2': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'subtitle-2'),
                        ( 'font-family': $body-font-family)
        ),
        'body-2': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'body-2'),
                        ( 'font-family': $body-font-family)
        ),
        'body-1': map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'body-1'),
                        ( 'font-family': $body-font-family)
        ),
        overline: map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'overline'),
                        ( 'font-family': $body-font-family)
        ),
        caption: map-merge(
                        map-get($headings, 'caption'),
                        ( 'font-family': $body-font-family)
        )
));
```

don't forget to add the main.scss in your `vue.config.js` 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables

Answer (score 1):

From Vuetify 2.0 doc, you should put default variables above the initial style import statement

And note: sometimes it only works by adding **!important**
Hope this will help you

```
// src/sass/main.scss

// Any changes to a default variable must be
// declared above the initial style import
$body-font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', cursive !important;

$heading-font-family: $body-font-family, cursive !important;

// Required for modifying core defaults
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$headings: map-merge(map_get($headings, h1), ( h1: ( font-family: $title-font) ));
```

In the documentation v2.0 said that, but is not working for me

Answer (score -1):

Try put the variables you want to modify **before** importing the vuetify styles.sass. This should fix this issue.

```
// main.scss

// variables want to modify
$font-size-root: 16px;
$body-font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
$heading-font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$btn-border-radius: 8px;

@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
```