# Override heading font Vuetify + Nuxt

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to change the default font for heading tags in a Vuetify + Nuxt setup. I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446246/override-vuetify-2-0-sass-variable-heading-font-family) but that doesn't apply to Nuxt In my assests/variables.scss:

```
// Ref: https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#customvariables
//
// The variables you want to modify
// $font-size-root: 20px;
@import '@fontsource/ledger/latin.css';
@import '@fontsource/raleway/latin.css';


$font-size-root: 16px;
$body-font-family: Raleway, Helvetica, sans-serif;
$heading-font-family: serif !important;


$headings: (
    'h1': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h2': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h3': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h4': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h5': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h6': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
);


@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
```

But my heading font is still Raleway. When I inspect the h1 tag I see this:
[image: image of devtools showing inspected h1 tag]

In the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#example-variable-file) they show the value the headings use:
[image]

Is there something additional I need to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the font family name to the variables you'd like to style then [install the font](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fontsource/roboto) you want and import it from `node_modules` or import via URL.

`assets/variables.scss`

```
 $font-size-root: 16px;
    
    $heading-font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    $body-font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      font-family: $heading-font-family;
    }
    
    @import "@fontsource/roboto/latin.css";
    @import "~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass"; //this has to be last
```